# C++ How to see if a number in an array is even or odd

Tags: c++

For example I have A[ 1 2 3 4 5 6 ]
and I want to put the even numbers in an array, and the odd ones in another array.

I assume I can't do something like this right?

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    if(a[i]%2!=0){
        b[j]=a[i];
        j++;
    }else{
        c[k]=a[i];
        k++;
    }
}
```

because I tried and it didn't work.
Thank you for your time :)
My whole code is this:

```
 int a[50],i,b[50],c[50],k,j,n;
    cout<<"n= ";cin>>n;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        cout<<"a["<<i<<"]: ";
        cin>>a[i];
    }

    cout<<"\na[ ";
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    }   
    cout<<"]";

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        if(a[i]%2!=0){
            b[j]=a[i];
            j++;
        }else{
            c[k]=a[i];
            k++;
        }
    }

     cout<<"\nb[ ";
    for(i=1;i<=j;i++){
        cout<<b[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<"]";

     cout<<"\nc[ ";
    for(i=1;i<=k;i++){
        cout<<c[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<"]";
```

And my other question is how can I take each number of an array individualy.
Like in the first part I want to see if one of the numbers is divisible by another given number

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're checking for parity. As far as I know a negative number is `a[i]<0`. Also what do you mean 'it doesn't work'.

Comment: In your code you are checking if the number is odd or even using `%2`. If you want positive or negative use `> or <`

Comment: "C++ How to see if a number in an array is possitive or negative" A number's sign doesn't change by virtue of being in an array. So write a function that tells you if a number is positive or negative. It should be quite easy to test such a function.

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant to say even or odd

Comment: You get an element of an array by indexing the array. (_If_ the `[`-operator was overloaded, it _should_ be with something in spirit.) `I tried and it didn't work` What has been the result, and what is wrong about it?

Comment: `Sorry, yes I meant to say even or odd` Don't apologize: edit and improve your post. (Update the title, too.)

Comment: by "I tried and it didn't work" I meant the program just stops after I write each element for the array.

Comment: There a _three_ arrays the code tries to show (with "identical" code not factored into a function): which has been the one this code showed a) with no visible progress ever after _or_ b) terminating unexpectedly? _Edit the question_, do _not_ comment comments asking for additional information or clarification.

Comment: (Do not be surprised to see "the loop body" coded `(in[i] % 2 ? odd[o++]:even[e++]) = in[i];` (feel free to be appalled).)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
```

you need (everywhere)

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
```

In C++, indices start from 0, and the loop variable is usually declared within the loop.

Beside, you should initialize j and k:
    int j=0, k=0;

Finally, in C++, variables are usually declared when they are needed:

```
int j=0, k=0;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    if(a[i]%2!=0){
        b[j]=a[i];
        j++;
    }else{
        c[k]=a[i];
        k++;
    }
}
```

In your final loops you need `i<j` and `i<k`, because j and k are incremented after the last time you wrote something into arrays.

You probably need cout << "\n" at the end.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate it. I figured it out with your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the number if odd by:

```
if (x % 2) {
    cout << "x is odd" << endl;
}
```

Therefore, the final code would be:

```
int N = 20; // array length
odd_arr[N], even_arr[N], odd_idx = 0, even_idx = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    if (A[i] % 2) {  // odd
        odd_arr[odd_idx] = A[i];
        odd_idx++;
    } else {  // even
        even_arr[even_idx] = A[i];
        even_idx++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did exactly the same and it displays big numbers ( I think is the ASCII code)

Comment: if I write the numbers 1 2 3 4 5, it displays like this: A[ 1 2 3 4 5] B[ 3 5 4732380] C[ 4 2000425106]

Comment: You did not initiate `j` and `k` in your code. Try: `j = 1; k = 1;` before using them.

Comment: (Seems you have broken the declarations in the second line (laudably!) commenting `N`.)

Answer (score 0):

First: you didn't initialize `j` and `k`, so when you store numbers into `b[]` and `c[]` you are likely be storing them into undetermined positions that may or may not lie within the array, invoking undefined behaviour.

Second: judging from your for loops, you seem to assume that arrays in C++ starts at element 1, when they actually starts at element 0. This doesn't hurt your program, as long as you choose a value for `n` not greater than 49.